# Boy's Love novel where the main character reincarnated as a female side character in a novel

Tags: story-identification, novel, reincarnation

She is a side character with pink hair. In the novel, she became a maid. One of the main characters is her brother.

I think the male lead is imprisoned by one of the lead characters. She tried to befriend the male lead of the story.

In one scene, there's a party for one of the lead characters and she and her brother saw each other. I think she was in disguise at the time, but her brother still recognized her.

I also remember a scene where the male lead escaped and tried to abduct her, but the lead characters saw it; I think it happened in the garden of the house of one of the lead characters.

That's all I remember.

Comment: BL means _Boy's Love_?

Comment: Yes .............

Comment: Are there any other details you remember? Like, the approximate year at which you read it for example. That would help to narrow it down (whether it's new or old).

Answer (score -1):

The Obsessive Maniac Is Trying To Confine Me.... That is the novel you are looking for.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Can you explain how it matches the details provided in the question?